How do I retrieve a long file path from a drag-and-drop operation on Windows, using Qt? Qt erroneously returns an empty array
Maybe I'm doing this wrong but if so I'm not sure how. Qt normally provides a QMimeData object for a drop event, which will contain the URLs of any associated files. On Windows, when such a file is long, exceeding the 260 character MAX_PATH, Qt seems to choke. hasUrls will return true, but the URL list will be empty. Internally I can see that it fails to grab the data with the COM function returning ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER.
What's odd here is that the information should be available. I noticed that when one asks for "application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="Shell IDList Array" from the mime data object, it returns successfully, and the information appears to be in there. I'm just not sure how to go about accessing it. I did reverse engineer the structure by staring at it for entirely too long and write some code that puts the file name together, but it's a very ugly hack. What's the proper way? And why does Qt fail anyway?
Just for reference sake, in case there turns out not to be any way to do it, here's the hack.
static QString evilWindowsMimeDataHack(QMimeData const *mimeData)
{
#define IsAligned(n) (static_cast<size_t>((reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(n) & 1) == 0))
    QByteArray shIdList = mimeData->data(uR"(application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="Shell IDList Array")"_s);
    if (shIdList.size() < 8LL + 35LL + 2LL)
        return {};

    char const *data = shIdList.constData();
    char const *end  = data + shIdList.size();
    char const *last = data + *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t const *>(data + 8);
    data += 35;

    // The drive letter is an ASCII string only. Technically a drive letter can be more
    // than one letter, so we treat it as a string. We use strnlen out of paranoia. It is
    // non-standard but definitely exists on Windows.
    QString str = uR"(\\?\)" + QString::fromLatin1(data, qsizetype(strnlen(data, end - data)));

    // We blindly add path separators later so ensure there isn't one.
    if (str.endsWith(u'\\'))
        str.chop(1);
    data += str.size() + 1;
    if (data >= end)
        return {};
    // Skip 28 bytes of unknown data. The data always appears to be aligned to an odd
    // offset. If we're at an even offset, skip 29 instead.
    data += 28 + IsAligned(data);

    while (data + 2 < end) {
        // ASCII short name (null-terminated)
        data += strnlen(data, end - data) + 1;
        // Skip 46 bytes of unknown data, or 47 if we're aligned.
        data += 46 + IsAligned(data);
        if (data >= end)
            break;

        // UTF-16 path segment (null-terminated). Qt won't accept an unaligned string,
        // so we must copy it to a buffer first. wcsnlen for paranoia as before.
        size_t len = wcsnlen(reinterpret_cast<wchar_t const *>(data), end - data);
        auto  *tmp = new char16_t[len + 1];
        memcpy(tmp, data, (len + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
        str.append(u'\\');
        str.append(reinterpret_cast<QChar *>(tmp), qsizetype(len));
        delete[] tmp;

        // Skip UTF-16 data and null terminator
        data += (len + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t);
        // Skip 16 bytes for each entry but the last, in which case we must skip 18.
        // The `last` offset is 4 bytes forward of where we are.
        data += data + 4 == last ? 18 : 16;
    }

    return str;
#undef IsAligned
}


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard#cfstr_shellidlist and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetpathfromidlistex

@Luke Yes, those were the first things I looked at, thanks. Obviously they didn't help, or I wouldn't be here.

Clearly Qt can't get paths longer than MAX_PATH. Since you can get the Shell ID List, try using SHGetPathFromIDListEx(), or SHCreateItemFromIDList() + IShellItem::GetDisplayName()...

... Or SHGetNameFromIDList()

I must have completely skipped over the part of your question where you stated what you had already tried and explained in detail why it "didn't help". Hope you figure it out!

@Roflcopter4 Sorry, but we cannot assume an unmentioned research as "obvious": we get thousands of questions every day, with a lot of them posted by users who just don't care to take even a few seconds to look up the official documentation. That's clearly not your case, but we have no way to know about it. "Obviously", Luke wouldn't probably have written that comment, if you mentioned that research. That said, did you check QWindowsMimeConverter (or QWinMime if you're on Qt5)?
